# Monitoring SSRS report server with AppDynamics

Tags: monitoring, sql

I've spent several days trying to figure out how to set up AppDynamics to monitor our SQL Server Reporting Servers, and am encountering the issue where multiple nodes for the same server and application are showing up.  I've tried following the configuration advice given [here](https://community.appdynamics.com/t5/NET-Agent-Installation/SSRS-Monitoring/td-p/32420), but with no success.  I either get hundreds of nodes (until the SSRS server stops responding) or no nodes at all.

Does anyone have any experience with this?  IS there a good step-by-step guide that I'm missing somewhere?